# Is there a way to monitor the temperature of CPU using lm_sensors?

Tags: fedora, temperature

I can successfully detect the temperatures of sensors using the sensors command. But is there a way or a tool so that I can dynamically monitor the temperatures of sensors conveniently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup [`munin`](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) to monitor CPU temp (as well as many other things) and graph them, by default it does sampling at 5min intervals.  It may be more than you want since it's really for monitoring a bunch of servers and such.

I also agree with @Keith, `gkrellm` is useful for desktop monitoring.

Comment: Also, `conky` is very useful too.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a tool to enable graphical monitoring from the terminal.
This is a terminal UI tool, so it can run on your desktop or over ssh. You can check it out at https://amanusk.github.io/s-tui/.

Simplest installation with pip:

```
sudo pip install s-tui
```

or if you do not have root permissions:

```
pip install s-tui --user
```

Screen shot

[image: s-tui demonstration]

Or download the executable from releases on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gkrellm](http://members.dslextreme.com/users/billw/gkrellm/gkrellm.html). It can monitor those and more. Also shows CPU, disk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on KDE you can check out:

- [ksensors](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56273-systray-sensor-applet) applet (KDE3)
- [system monitor](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Plasma/Plasmoids#System_Monitor) plasma widget (KDE4)